# Tabbar Color Change

Tags: ios, tabbar

I have tab bar as shown in attached figure. I would like to make this blue color ,which I believe default, to green. Is there way to make it ?

[image]

Comment: See the docs for `UITabBar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this at your view controller.

```
[[self tabBarController] tabBar].tintColor =[UIColor greenColor];
```